Creating start and end date - Python
I am still pretty new to pythons. I am trying to create a python code to pull the earliest extraction as start time. When the conditon becomes Y , then I would like to create an end date based on condition:
Sample Data table:



ID
SUB ID
Extraction Date
Conditon met (Y/N)




1
x
2023-01-02
N


1
y
2023-01-02
N


1
x
2023-02-15
N


2
v
2023-02-15
N


2
z
2023-02-15
N


1
x
2023-03-15
Y


2
v
2023-03-15
Y



I have tried a few ways to pull the data but not luck:
df['start date'] = df.groupby(['ID','SUB ID'], as_index = False)['Extraction Date].transform(min).reset_index()

df['start date'] = df.groupby(['ID','SUB ID'], as_index = False)['Extraction Date].min()

df['end date'] = df.query(Condition met (Y/N) == Y).groupby(['ID','SUB ID'], as_index = False['Extraction Date].transform(max).reset_index()

df['end date'] = df.query(Condition met (Y/N) == Y).groupby(['ID','SUB ID'], as_index = False['Extraction Date].min()

What I would like to get:



ID
SUB ID
Extraction Date
Conditon met (Y/N)
Start Date
End Date




1
x
2023-01-02
N
2023-01-02
N/A


1
y
2023-01-02
N
2023-01-02
N/A


1
x
2023-02-15
N
2023-01-02
N/A


2
v
2023-02-15
N
2023-02-15
N/A


2
z
2023-02-15
N
2023-02-15
N/A


1
x
2023-03-15
Y
2023-01-02
2023-03-15


2
v
2023-03-15
Y
2023-02-15
2023-03-15




You can use groupby and transform("min") to get the Start Date, and loc to get the End Date:
df["Start Date"] = df.groupby(["ID", "SUB ID"])["Extraction Date"].transform("min")
df.loc[df["Condition met (Y/N)"] == "Y", "End Date"] = df["Extraction Date"]

   ID SUB ID Extraction Date Condition met (Y/N) Start Date   End Date
0   1      x      2023-01-02                   N 2023-01-02        NaT
1   1      y      2023-01-02                   N 2023-01-02        NaT
2   1      x      2023-02-15                   N 2023-01-02        NaT
3   2      v      2023-02-15                   N 2023-02-15        NaT
4   2      z      2023-02-15                   N 2023-02-15        NaT
5   1      x      2023-03-15                   Y 2023-01-02 2023-03-15
6   2      v      2023-03-15                   Y 2023-02-15 2023-03-15


You are almost there, ideally what you want to use the groupby for "ID", "SUB ID", Extraction then use transform with min, which you have done.
you can then go ahead to get to use max to extract the latest dates
I am following the code you have provided, all I did was modify it so you can still retain the concept which you already had.
Here is a code snippet used to build on your code:
import pandas as pd

# Sample Data
data = {
    "ID": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2],
    "SUB ID": ["x", "y", "x", "v", "z", "x", "v"],
    "Extraction Date": [
        "2023-01-02",
        "2023-01-02",
        "2023-02-15",
        "2023-02-15",
        "2023-02-15",
        "2023-03-15",
        "2023-03-15",
    ],
    "Condition met (Y/N)": ["N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "Y"],
}

# Convert to DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["Extraction Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Extraction Date"])

# Calculate Start Date
df["Start Date"] = df.groupby(["ID", "SUB ID"])["Extraction Date"].transform("min")

# Calculate End Date
# filter rows where the condition is 'Y'
condition_y_df = df[df["Condition met (Y/N)"] == "Y"]

# map latest extraction date with condition 'Y' to each group
end_dates = condition_y_df.groupby(["ID", "SUB ID"])["Extraction Date"].transform("max")

# create series with correct end dates
end_date_series = condition_y_df[["ID", "SUB ID", "Extraction Date"]].copy()
end_date_series["End Date"] = end_dates

# Merge original DataFrame
df = df.merge(
    end_date_series[["ID", "SUB ID", "Extraction Date", "End Date"]],
    on=["ID", "SUB ID", "Extraction Date"],
    how="left",
)

# Fill NaT values with 'N/A'
df["End Date"] = df["End Date"].fillna("N/A")


print(df)


Result:
   ID SUB ID Extraction Date Condition met (Y/N) Start Date             End Date
0   1      x      2023-01-02                   N 2023-01-02                  N/A
1   1      y      2023-01-02                   N 2023-01-02                  N/A
2   1      x      2023-02-15                   N 2023-01-02                  N/A
3   2      v      2023-02-15                   N 2023-02-15                  N/A
4   2      z      2023-02-15                   N 2023-02-15                  N/A
5   1      x      2023-03-15                   Y 2023-01-02       2023-03-15
6   2      v      2023-03-15                   Y 2023-02-15       2023-03-15


